Cavity field e.g. in laser - is it more than optical photons, like standaing EM wave? Does optical isolator block it?
Reading e.g. this "Quantum theory of the laser" script, there is cavity field - kind of standing wave in laser resonator, but the question is: are these just optical photons, or maybe also something more like standing EM wave?
For example in Purcell effect, just presence of such optical cavity/resonator stimulates photon emission - like there was something e.g. standing EM wave before these photons?
A related question: does optical isolator block such cavity field coupling, or maybe only photons? - experimentally e.g. does below backward placed optical isolator block backward ASE (amplified spontaneous emission)?


Its a good question ... but I think it can not be answered.  It is kind of like what comes first ... the chicken or the egg. The EM field is full of zero point energy that we can barely detect .... exciting electrons in atoms in an optical cavity is like waiting for the pot to boil.

Yes the optical isolator, which is effectively the cavity, decides what will resonate in the fibre. Resonance influence can extend quite a distance in this apparatus, it is as if the EM field extends over the whole experiment .... which it does because the EM field is continuous in all space.

@PhysicsDave the proposed test: "does backward OI block backward ASE" is relatively easy to perform if having equipment (I don't have). It would check if optical isolator blocks not only photons, but also different types of EM coupling between laser and erbium - e.g. through delocalized standing EM waves like in optical cavity, not necessarily blocked by optical isolator (?)

The OI is not really a blocker .. it is just a resonator for the 1550nm only.  Saying other frequencies are suppressed is kind of misleading ... its more that the tap is turned on for 1550nm.  There's no directionality to the resonator.
